# Scalability and fault tollerance servers. How do it?

Tags: php, mysql, mono, cluster-computing, virtualization

In our project we have a front-end part with PHP and Apache, a MySQL database and some Mono servers that do some logic (chat, etc...)

It's all completed but before starting and buy the servers i want know how make them scalable and be fault tollerance. We want buy the servers on So You Start.

How can we proceed? What we must buy (possible cheap)? We thinked about a virtualization but we don't know how move.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't you employ a cloud approach, AWS for example?

Comment: Architect with no single-point-of failure; make sessions sharable between servers; replicate your database; re-invent the wheel

Comment: Hi Mark, so what is your solution?

Comment: @rontornambe i don't know where to start... can you help me?

Comment: There is no one solution: I've highlighted a number of elements that I apply for most infrastructures: load balanced webheads, facility to roll out additional webheads on demand, database on a separate cluster with replication and automatic failover, session maintained in a redis cluster with replication and persistence, etc, all geographically dispersed so loss of one datacentre won't take out the whole system.

Comment: This is an area where cloud hosting really does come into its own; and really is a lot cheaper than it seems when you factor support and cost of ownership into running your own servers

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has a lot of very good documentation about how to architect their cloud services. I would suggest you start with a free (for 1 year) Usage Tier for learning AWS and testing your application. The free tier It enables you to setup a Unix and Windows instance as well as RDS (Relational Database Server) and email service. You can later add fail-over servers located in geographically dispersed locations. You can also scale easily by adding (and removing) instances as needed.

Start with this [overview](https://aws.amazon.com/free/cloud-computing-free-tier/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=AWS_Free_Tier_2013_C&sc_country=US&sc_publisher=Google&sc_medium=b_core_cloud_computing_bmm-web_services&sc_content=40951076442&sc_detail=%2Bamazon%20%2Bservices&sc_category=aws_cloud_computing&sc_segment=cloud_computing&sc_matchtype=b).

Answer (score 0):

In AWS you can start small and then use AutoScaling with ELB and cloudfront to really scale up as needed.
http://dailytechscape.com